# How to do 2 groupings in a SQL query, and export to JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Here's an example, in csv form, of my mySQL store when.

```
trek_id, number, name, value, units, userID, deviceID, lat        , lng
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     88,      4, Hum ,   720, PPB  ,     96,         1, 40.0215268, -105.2177324
     88,      4, PM10,   720, PPB  ,     96,         1, 40.0215268, -105.2177324
     88,      6, Pres,   730, PPB  ,     96,         1, 40.0215299, -105.2177096
     88,      6, PM10,   730, PPB  ,     96,         1, 40.0215299, -105.2177096
```

So a `trek_id` has multiple `number` values, and each number contains multiple measurements. I would love to know how to query this so I could eventually insert into a json object that looks like this:

```
{  
"88":{  
   "4":{  
      "lat":"40.0215268",
      "lng":"-105.2177324",
      "userID":96,
      "deviceID":"1",
      "measurements":[
        ["Hum",
         "PPB",  
           720
        ],
        ["PM10",
         "PPB",
         720
        ]
      ]
    },
   "6":{  
      "lat":"40.0215299",
      "lng":"-105.2177096",
      "userID":96,
      "deviceID":"1",
      "measurements":[
        ["Pres",
         "PPB",  
           730
        ],
        ["PM10",
         "PPB",
         720
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So essentially I need to group on `trek_id` and then again on `number`.

Comment: Having in mind the final result, it makes no sense to group by something in the sql statement. Fetch all records - as displayed, loop through them (using the programming language of your choice) and build your (json) array

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first: SQL results are FLAT tables. They don't have sub groups or sub array. So you need to handle all sub-grouping in the display code.

Second: You existing data is already perfect for the DISPLAY code (let's say PHP) to create a multi-dimensional array to transform into JSON.

--- HINT PSEUDO_CODE ---

```
<?php
// assume  $results contains your data AND SORTED BY trek_id, number, name

$cur_trek   = null;
$cur_number = null;
$json = array();

foreach ($results as $res) {
   if ($cur_trek != $res['trek_id']) {
      $cur_trek   = $res['trek_id'] ;
      $json[$cur_trek] = array();
      $cur_number = null;
   }
   if ($cur_number != $res['number']) {
       $cur_number = $res['number'];
       $json[$cur_trek][$cur_number] = 
         array(
           'lat'          => $res['lat'],
           'lng'          => $res['lng'],
           'userID'       => $res['userID'],
           'deviceID'     => $res['deviceID'],
           'measurements' => array();
         );
   }
   $json[$cur_trek][$cur_number]['measurements'][] = 
     array($res['name'], $res['units'], $res['value']);
}

$json = json_encode($json);
```